# Store multiple Values in one session variable in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, session-variables

I want to store college IDs in a session variable that each ID should get stored in same session. i want it when user click on ADD button. so whenever the ADD button would be clicked that ID Should get stored in `choice` session variable.

here is what i have tried.

**views.py**

```
def my_choices(request, cid):  # when user is making the choices
    clg = college.objects.all()
    title = "Choice Filling"
    page = "Choice Filling"
    stud = student.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
    clgid = college.objects.get(id=cid)
    choice_list = []
    if stud.isactive != 1:
        messages.error(request, "Your registration process is incomplete.")
    else:
        choice_list.insert(len(choice_list), clgid.name)
        print(choice_list)
        request.session['choices'] = choice_list

    return render(request, 'college_list.html', {'cid': cid, 'clg': clg, 'title': title,
                                                 'choice':choice_list})
```

**models.py**

```
class college(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    institute_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class student(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

I want to store `cid` for every click in `choice_list` but it's not storing multiple values, instead it overrides the previous value and store new every time. i tried `choice_list.insert(..)` also but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You're initiating the choice_list as an empty list, instead of loading it from the session

```
choice_list = []
```

Replace it with:

```
choice_list = request.session.get('choices', [])
```

Your new function should now be

```
def my_choices(request, cid):  # when user is making the choices
   clg = college.objects.all()
   title = "Choice Filling"
   page = "Choice Filling"
   stud = student.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
   clgid = college.objects.get(id=cid)

   # get choice list from your session
   choice_list = request.session.get('choices', [])

   if stud.isactive != 1:
       messages.error(request, "Your registration process is incomplete.")
   else:
       choice_list.insert(len(choice_list), clgid.name)
       print(choice_list)
       request.session['choices'] = choice_list

       # the next line shouldn't be required, but if the code still doesnt work, uncomment it
       # request.session.modified = True
   return render(request, 'college_list.html', {'cid': cid, 'clg': clg, 'title': title,
                                             'choice':choice_list})
```

Also, if you might have to tell django that the session has been changed. Put this code before returning your view (or after the session edit)

```
request.session.modified = True
```